# How do I get the name of a form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

How do I get the name of a form in Javascript?

I have tried stuff like:

```
document.forms[0].name
document.forms[0].id //I have both name and id set
```

Comment: found my problem... there was a typo else where that made it seems as if this wasnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. Should both work.

Are you 100% sure you have no other form(s) in the document?
Does

```
document.getElementById('form_id').name
```

work? (form_id being the ID you assigned).

Comment: If I do that then I already know the name/id of the form. There is only 1 form.

Answer (score 2):

`document.forms[0].name` works for me in both IE7 and FF3.5... I guess there must be some other problem.

(Are you trying to access the name from a `<script>` element at the top of the HTML, before the form has appeared?)